# ¿Como hacer clip path de un canvas y expandir su tamaño? (React + Tensorflow + Facetracking + Canvas)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, tensorflow

Voy a dar un poco de contexto de contexto, estoy haciendo uso de los modelos de tensorflow para realizar la detección facial e intentar realizar un filtro de boca grande en un canvas. estoy intentando crear un recorte con clip de la zona de la boca para luego expandirlo pero no he podido hacerlo correctamente, no tengo mucha experiencia usando el canvas y necesito ayuda por que no entiendo que puede estar pasando y creo que voy por el camino correcto.

Con el siguiente código logro hacer el filtro con un rectángulo, tomando los "landmarks" de tensorflow.

```
const scaledKeypoints = (keypoints) => {
  const scaledMesh = keypoints?.map((cord) => {
    return [cord.x, cord.y];
  });
  return scaledMesh;
};

export const bigMouth = (ctx, video, faces, tf) => {
  faces.forEach((element) => {
    const scaledMesh = scaledKeypoints(element.keypoints);
    /* console.log(scaledMesh[27][1]); */
    let lTop = scaledMesh[0][1];
    let lLeft = scaledMesh[57][0];
    let lBot = scaledMesh[18][1];
    let lRig = scaledMesh[287][0];
    let lWid = lRig - lLeft;
    let lHei = lBot - lTop;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);

    ctx.drawImage(
      video,
      lLeft,
      lTop,
      lWid,
      lHei,
      lLeft - lWid * 0.5,
      lTop - lHei * 0.5,
      2 * lWid,
      2 * lHei
    );
  });
};
```

He intentando mejorar el recorte con los puntos de referencia correspondientes a los labios para intentar expandirlo pero no lo he logrado, me podrian ayudar con esto por favor?

Intente con el siguiente codigo pero no me funciona correctamente.

```
export const lens = (ctx, video, faces, tf) => {
  faces.forEach((e) => {
    const scaledMesh = scaledKeypoints(e.keypoints);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(
      scaledMesh[mouthLandmarksx2[0][0]][0],
      scaledMesh[mouthLandmarksx2[0][1]][1]
    );
    mouthLandmarksx2.forEach((cord) => {
      ctx.lineTo(scaledMesh[cord[0]][0], scaledMesh[cord[0]][1]);
      ctx.lineTo(scaledMesh[cord[1]][0], scaledMesh[cord[1]][1]);
    });
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    // TRY MOUTH
    let lTop = scaledMesh[0][1];
    let lLeft = scaledMesh[57][0];
    let lBot = scaledMesh[18][1];
    let lRig = scaledMesh[287][0];
    let lWid = lRig - lLeft;
    let lHei = lBot - lTop;

    ctx.drawImage(
      video,
      lLeft,
      lTop,
      lWid,
      lHei,
      lLeft - lWid * 0.5,
      lTop - lHei * 0.5,
      2 * lWid,
      2 * lHei
    );
  });
};
```

Aqui dejo el repositorio por si quieren ver mejor el codigo: https://github.com/J-Roma/face-filter.git